# Error when using while loop in another while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I was trying to do a stock recording function which post out product in rows using while loop and the stock count in another while loop but when i run the code it returns error in the second while loop and i'm not sure which part did i went wrong. Need some help here!

Here's the code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');  
        mysql_select_db('EmployeeDB');  
        $rproduct = "SELECT Product FROM `tbl_user` GROUP BY Product";
        $result = mysql_query($rproduct);

        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $prod = $row1['Product'];   
            echo "<tr><th>$prod</th>";
            $rstock = mysql_query('SELECT opening, closing FROM tbl_user WHERE Product = $prod ORDER BY date');

            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rstock)) {
                echo "<td>".$row2['opening']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['closing']."</td>";
            }

            echo"</tr>";
        }
```

[image: error]

Comment: What error you are getting? using `JOIN`s would be better.

Comment: use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql.mysql is deprecated

Comment: (1) `Product` is probably a string, so it should be quoted -> `... WHERE Product = "$prod" ...`. (2) Anytime you are doing a query inside a loop, you could probably just do this with a `JOIN` **especially** when you are selecting from the same table

Comment: error im getting is `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\UserReport.php on line 48`

Comment: @Sean product is the data row im calling from sql table

Comment: @Shanukk already try using mysqli but still getting the same error

Comment: @RaymondChok what type is column Product in your table?
Write out your query - put them to the phpmyadmin (or other tool) and check are you getting any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick solution

Replace this line:

```
            $rstock = mysql_query('SELECT opening, closing FROM tbl_user WHERE Product = $prod ORDER BY date');
```

With:

```
$rstock = mysql_query("SELECT opening, closing FROM tbl_user WHERE Product = '$prod' ORDER BY date");
```

There are two problems with the original line:

1. You were using a variable inside a single quoted string and that is wrong, it only works with double quoted strings.
2. the variable $prod needs to be wrapped in single quotes because you are searching for a string, without the quote you were actually telling mysql to search for a row where column product equals the value inside a column which name is whatever inside variabe $prod.

## Better solution

Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql because it is deprecated, and prepare statements instead of just putting variables inside strings.

Comment: Can you use echo mysql_error() after the line I mentioned up there and tell me what it said?

Comment: it shows `Unknown column 'Shokubutsu' in 'where clause'`, but in my database i have this data.... weird

Comment: Good to know, would you mark my answer as correct? and please use the better solution or use a php framework it will be much easier and faster :)